Unintentionally previous commit also deployed production
I have three developers. They are sending merge requests from individual branches to my staging branch. If I accept a single commit and move it to production, it will move to production properly. However, when I push the next commit, another developer's request will also push the previous commit to production. How to avoid this and How can I fix this issue? If its possible, please provide step-by-step instructions
I tried multiple types but its showing same issues
